# Error with averaging program (Java), (Debugging)

Tags: java, debugging

Of course I could have simply done everything in the main method, but that wouldn't help me practice the little I know with Java. So I made, or tried to make, an averaging program, where you input three variables, it calculates the average in a different method and returns the end result. Here is my code:

```
package test;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testingclass {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double[] grades = new double[3];
        System.out.println("Enter 3 grades you want to average out: ");
        grades[0] = input.nextDouble();
        grades[1] = input.nextDouble();
        grades[2] = input.nextDouble();

        display(grades);
        System.out.println(average);

    }

    public static double display(double[] x){
        double total = 0;
        for(int counter = 0; counter < x.length; counter++){
            total = total + x[counter];
        }

        double average = total/x.length;
        return average;
    }
}
```

So I have everything done, but now I don't know where to go, and when I did `System.out.println(average);` it told me that average wasn't a variable. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because `average` is local to your `display` method.  Try:

```
System.out.println(display(grades));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. One more thing, can you explain the return command? I don't understand how returning values like that work. You call (displayer(grades)); in a print command and it automatically knows to give you that with the return command. I do not completely understand this concept.

Comment: @Code123 You are basically inputting `grades` into the `double[] x` parameter in your display method, which is then processed to get the average, and a double is returned

Comment: Another way of saying it without getting too computer sciencey: The `return` statement tells the code to replace the call to the function with the value given in the return statement.  In your case, you are telling the code to replace the expression `display(grades)` with what you compute for `average`.

Answer (score 3):

`average` isn't a local variable in your main method, only in the `display` method. Use:

```
System.out.println(display(grades));
```

Think of it this way, you are calling your display method with `display(grades);`, which returns the average of the inputted double array. In this case `grades` is the array to be averaged.